# Setting pixel value to its percentile in a neighbourhood

Tags: python, filter, numpy, scipy, percentile

For spatial analysis purposes, I am trying to set up a filter that would, for a pixel in a given neighbourhood, give the percentile of *this* pixel in its neighbourhood (defined by a structuring element).

Below is my best shot so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import scipy.stats as sp

def get_percentile(values, radius=3):
  # Retrieve central pixel and neighbours values
  cur_value = values[4]
  other_values = np.delete(values, 4)

  return sp.percentileofscore(other_values, cur_value)/100

def percentiles(image):

  # definition of the neighbourhood (structuring element)
  footprint = np.array([[1,1,1],
                  [1,1,1],
                  [1,1,1]])

  # Using generic_filter to apply sequentially a my own user-defined
  # function (`get_percentile`) in the filter
  results = ndimage.generic_filter(
    image, 
    get_percentile, 
    footprint=footprint, 
    mode='constant', 
    cval=np.nan)

  return results

# Pick dimensions for a dummy example
dims = [12,15]
# Generate dummy example
df = np.random.randn(np.product(dims)).reshape(dims[0], dims[1])

percentiles(df)
```

It sort of work, but:
1. I'm sure the code is not really optimal, and could run faster
2. The dimension of my neighbourhood is hard coded. Something I would like is to better identify the central pixel on which I'm applying the filter (`footprint`) from its neighbours according to this filter.

Comment: Why not use scipy.ndimage.filters.percentile_filter?

Comment: As far as I understand, `scipy.ndimage.filters.percentile_filter` is replacing the central pixel value by the N-percentile computed on its neighbourhood (N is chosen by the user). In my case, I want to compute what is the percentile of the central pixel in its neighbourhood (this is given by `number_of_lower_neighbours/(size_of_neighbourhood^2 - 1)`)